# Grouping any tags with quantifier to find text between tags

Tags: regex

I have this `/(<s*\w*>){1,2}\s*\@item@(<\s*\/\w*>){1,2}/g`
is this possible to group `<s*\w*>` and `<\s*\/\w*>` for quantifier without using
parenthesis? Because it ruin my split, i can do `/\@item@/` but i wanna check the possibility for tags. (1 or 2). 
I tried without parenthesis but it check only one tag.

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon). Replace `(<s*\w*>)` with `(?:<s*\w*>)` and the rest like this.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am new with regex and i missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [*non-capturing groups*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon):

```
/(?:<s*\w*>){1,2}\s*\@item@(?:<\s*\/\w*>){1,2}/g
  ^^                        ^^
```